# How to calculate Count of a Filtered Employees based upon a Measure in Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have a dataset of employees working on month-to-month basis,

The dataset looks something like this,

[image]

I have a **Slicer for Date Range** from which the user can select any date range and data will be filtered accordingly.

I have a **Matrix Visual** that shows allocation of employees **month-wise**. There is an additional Filter is applied on this Matrix visual, through which the visual only shows those employees which have been allocated (have allocation > 0) on all months being filtered. For example, If I am filtering from August to December, then only the records which have allocation greater than 0 FOR ALL THE MONTHS (August to December) will be shown. I have also attached two examples below to demonstrate this,

[image: As only the employee with Emp ID = 3 was allocated on all the months from August to Ddecember, so his record is shown only]

(As only the employee with Emp ID = 3 was allocated on all the months from August to Ddecember, so his record is shown only)

[image]

(3 Employees were allocated in both the months of Nov and December, so their records are shown)

This is the measure that I am using currently in this Matrix Visual to filter out the employees which don't have allocation > 0 for all the months being filtered.

```
Employee Allocated All Months Boolean = 
Var _count = 
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Calendar'[Month]), 
            FILTER(
                ALLSELECTED(Competency),
                Competency[Emp Code] = MAX(Competency[Emp Code])
            )
        )
    Var _total = 
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Calendar'[Month]), 
            ALLSELECTED(Competency)
        )
RETURN 
    IF(_count = _total, 1)
```

My problem comes in the other visuals. I have a visual that **shows Total Unique Employees** in the Data ***(As can be seen in the images above)***. I want this Visual to also act similarly (that is, **if the employee is not allocated in all the months being filtered**, then he shouldn't be considered in this count. So, if I am filtering from August to December, so this visual should show **1 employee** only. And if I am filtering from November to December, so it should show 3 Employees)

Same for the field-wise breakdown of the employees count, only those employees should be counted which are allocated in that specific date range.

**MY ATTEMPT**

*I tried to achieve this by changing my Total Resources Measure with the following DAX, however it doesn't seem to be giving correct results,*

```
Total Unique Resources - Test = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Competency[Emp Code]), 
    FILTER(
        Competency, 
        [Employee Allocated All Months Boolean] = 1
    )
)
```

Results that I got with this DAX are as follows (it gives correct result for the Total Unique Resources/Employees) but doesn't give correct results in the Grade-wise Breakdown of the Resources (where technically it should show only one employee)

[image]

Can anyone help me out in this?

> **You can also download the complete Power BI File:**
> **https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pHapxFQ9MafSwt3yrqN3x5oKocv4pFcv/view?usp=sharing**